# Comparing data types, why does the test not see None?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, data-structures, python-3.8, nonetype

I have this function which checks an input data structure that it has the correct fields.

```
def validate_response(RequiredTypes: RawCustomResponseDataStruct, ResultToCheck: RawCustomResponseData) -> bool:
if isinstance(RequiredTypes, dict) and isinstance(ResultToCheck, dict):
    return all(k in ResultToCheck and validate_response(RequiredTypes[k], ResultToCheck[k]) for k in RequiredTypes)
if isinstance(RequiredTypes, list) and isinstance(ResultToCheck, list):
    return all(validate_response(RequiredTypes[0], c) for c in ResultToCheck)
if isinstance(RequiredTypes, type):
    return isinstance(ResultToCheck, RequiredTypes)
return False
```

The class and it's fields look like this: (I've made the dictionary replica so that isinstance can be used as I don't want to import more libraries).

```
class Crawler(TypedDict):
is_crawler: bool
category: Union[str, None]
last_seen: Union[str, None]

CrawlerStruct = {
    "is_crawler": bool,
    "category": Union[str, None],
    "last_seen": Union[str, None]}
```

When I run this test with the following input:

```
def test_validate_response():
ResultToCheck = {"ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 isBot3", "type": "browser", "brand": "Apple", "name": "Mac", "url": "https://about.google/", "os": {"name": "macOS 10.14 Mojave", "code": "macos_10_14", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave", "family": "macOS", "family_code": "macos", "family_vendor": "Apple Inc.", "icon": "https://assets.userstack.com/icon/os/macosx.png", "icon_large": "https://assets.userstack.com/icon/os/macosx_big.png"}, "device": {"is_mobile_device": False, "type": "desktop", "brand": "Apple", "brand_code": "apple", "brand_url": "https://www.apple.com/", "name": "Mac"}, "browser": {"name": "Chrome", "version": "71.0.3578.98", "version_major": "71", "engine": "WebKit/Blink"}, "crawler": {"is_crawler": False, "category": None, "last_seen": None}}
result = validate_response(RawCustomResponseDataStruct, user_agent)
assert result is True
```

It fails.

However if I remove the union, and just use `str` for the class and dictionary and run the test changing the "crawler" object to have the following values

```
"crawler": {"is_crawler": False, "category": "None", "last_seen": "None"}
```

It passes. Why is this? Why is it not recognising the None type?

Comment: A few points, you're not passing `ResultToCheck` to your `validate_response()` function. Instead you're passing an unknown `user_agent` variable.

You're also calling `isinstance(RequiredTypes, type)`, where `type` is just a function to get the type, it would always return false for whatever variable `RequiredTypes` is.

Comment: @MarthinusBosman Oh okay, while trying things, I must have mixed it up but I did pass that `ResultToCheck` into the test before. 

The second part I don't follow because it does return true if I pass ResultToCheck with the following edit `"crawler": {"is_crawler": False, "category": "None", "last_seen": "None"} ` So surely it is comparing the types.